# selecting specific columns from R datatable

Tags: r

I have a R dataframe and I need to select first n columns and some other columns using name.

Can I do it in a single statement ?

Say I need to choose columns from 1 to 10 and columns named as A,B,C etc

Answer (score 3):

`select` from `dplyr` allows to do that.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% select(1:3, 'am', 'carb') %>% head

#                   mpg cyl disp am carb
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160  1    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160  1    4
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  1    1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258  0    1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360  0    2
#Valiant           18.1   6  225  0    1
```

In base R, you can use either index or names at a given time, so you can either  do :

```
mtcars[, c(names(mtcars)[1:3], 'am', 'carb')]
```

Or :

```
mtcars[, c(1:3, match(c('am', 'carb'), names(mtcars)))]
```